# Should I start developing facebook applications now?

Tags: facebook

I want to develop a facebook application but it seems that they're changing their API, I mean, they're changing the old REST for the new Graph API, so my question is, should I start learning the old REST API and make my application there? or should I wait for facebook to completely change their API?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the first question is, do you know the scheduled timelines for this project to complete? If no, then I think its better you start learning the old REST API and also keep an eye on the changes that are going on. I am sure they wont stop the support for OLD REST API, since there might be few applications already deployed using those older APIs, so you should not worry about the changes going around and concentrate on your project to complete.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had to do a port or something.